# Homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

My question is how to prove that for $m \neq n$: $\mathbb{R}^2 $ without $n$ points and $\mathbb{R}^2 $ without $m$ points are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Look at their fundamental groups!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $R_n = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{n\mbox{ points}\}$ retracts onto a wedge of $n$ circles, so that its fundamental group is free on $n$ generators.   So if $m\neq n$, the two spaces $R_m$ and $R_n$ cannot be homotopy-equivalent (because, as Zhen Lin points out below, two free groups of different rank are non-isomorphic).

Comment: (One should show that the free group on $m$ generators is not isomorphic to the free group on $n$ generators if $m \ne n$...)

Comment: @ZhenLin Indeed, and thank you.  I have added a point mentioning this.

Comment: An easy way to see this is to abelianize.

Comment: And how do I know that the fundamental group of a wedge of $n$ circles is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ ?

Comment: @Anne, do you know van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: Or, e.g., Proposition 1.40 in Hatcher. $F_n$ acts freely on its Cayley graph (an infinite tree of valence $n$) and the quotient is an $n$-fold wedge of circles.  Since the tree is simply connected, this is a universal covering map.